# Will console.log()'ing type "any" variable cause error on Typescript?

Tags: javascript, typescript, console.log, any

I will console.log(variable: any) in Typescript, but I don't want it to cause an error, and I don't want to add try{}catch block everywhere. Will console.log(any) cause any type of error? Or will it print everything I give?

```
public print(data:any){
    console.log(data);
}
```

Comment: What happens when you try?

Comment: it shouldn't cause an error. have you tested it an experienced an error? if so, what does the error say?

Comment: What error do you anticipate?

Comment: I haven't faced an error, but I don't want it to cause any error, since it is a simple point.

Comment: If `console.log` happens not to exist at runtime you'll get an error, but it's hard to imagine a problem that would be caused by passing in an offending `data` value to an otherwise-functional `console.log()` implementation.

Comment: No it won't throw error and if value is null then it will write "undefined". FYI - if you console.log any field of data(with null value) with "." accessor ,then it will throw error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it will not. Typescript is used to statically analyze code.

MDN words about console log (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Console/log):

> The Console method log() outputs a message to the web console. The
>   message may be a single string (with optional substitution values), or
>   it may be any one or more JavaScript objects.